# Copy range to another sheet with Google Appscript

Tags: google-apps-script, copy, setvalue

I have written a script that aims at copying a range of data from one sheet to two other separate sheets, one after the other.
The data I want to copy is in a sheet called "New entries for the Database". The destination sheets are "BackEndDatabase" and "New Stores for the week".

The script is working fine for the first sheet but doesn't do the same fot eh second one. So, it runs and copies the correct data into the "BackEndDatabase" sheet but does nothing in the "New Stores for the week" sheet. I am not sure what I might be doing wrong. The correct SHEET IDs are being used in both instances.

The script is as follows:

```
  function addnewentries() {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('New Entries for Database')
    var range = sh.getDataRange().offset(0, 0);
    var data = range.getValues();
    var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('BackEndDatabase')
    ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
    var ts1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('New Stores for the week')
    ts1.getRange(ts1.getLastRow() + 1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
```

Thank you.

Comment: Why not reduce the possibility of error by storing the variable for the spreadsheet? `var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("sheet id");` then you need only call `ss.getSheetByName("sheet name")` instead? I don't see anything wrong with your code here, so my only thought is your IDs are incorrect. Also, you've scrolled all the way down in your second sheet, right? Just in case a cell was being used before your first paste?

Comment: Adding spaces to your sheet names isn't a good practice. Use underscore or the same naming convention as in 'BackEndDatabase'.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
function addnewentries() {

  var sh = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('New Entries for Database')
  var range = sh.getDataRange();//offset not needed
  var data = range.getValues();
  var ts = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('BackEndDatabase');//missing semicolon

  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow() + 1, 1, range.getHeight(), range.getWidth()).setValues(data);//use Height and Width of the range in case first row has fewer columns
  var ts1 = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SHEET_ID').getSheetByName('New Stores for the week');//missing semicolon
  ts1.getRange(ts1.getLastRow() + 1, 1,range.getHeight(), range.getWidth()).setValues(data);//again use Height and Width of the range in case first row has fewer columns
}
```

Take a look at the comments for each line.